Проблема с телеграм ботом на основе g4f
Написал тг бота на основе g4f на python. Поработал он около 1 дня, и пользователям начала выскакивать данная ошибка: Ваш IP-адрес был заблокирован из-за срабатывания системы обнаружения злоупотреблений, возможно, из-за использования облачного сервера, такого как Tencent Cloud, или иностранного прокси (VPN) для доступа к этому сайту. Если вы используете VPN, вы можете продолжить использование, отключив VPN или прокси.
Сайт службы: https://chat18.aichatos8.com
) (не реклама)
Пробовал разных провайдеров, но выходила ошибка "aichat is not working" и так со всеми. Пробовал VPN и прокси - тоже самое. Помогите решить ошибку! Заранее спасибо.
